# How to add sheet to excel when called inside a function?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have written a code in python that calls stock market data from an API, performs some functions and puts the results in an excel sheet. the only problem is whenever I call this function, it overwrites the new data on the existing sheet instead of creating a new sheet and entering the data into that. The function looks like this:

```
     def getCSV(self, symbols):
        for i in symbols:
            getIntradayData(i, self.shorttrend, self.longtrend, self.interval)
            
        text=self.exchangeName
        x = text.split(">")
        text=x[1]
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tradingviewdata.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(text) 
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
        worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 15)

        worksheet.write('A1', 'Symbol', bold)
        worksheet.write('B1', 'Code', bold)
        worksheet.write('C1', 'Code Short', bold)
        
        row = 1
        col = 0   

        for Symbol, Code, cs in (listfinal):
            try:
                worksheet.write_string (row, col,Symbol)
                worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, Code)
                worksheet.write_string(row, col + 2, cs)
                
                row += 1
            except:
                pass

        workbook.close()
```

Here, `symbols` is a list of stock symbols which is passed as a query to `getIntradayData()`.

`getIntradayData()` takes all the parameters, fetches the data from the API and updates the answer in a global list called `listfinal`, which you can see is getting called in the last `for` loop for writing the data into the excel.

A new excel sheet is formed like this

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tradingviewdata.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(text)
```

Where `tradingviewdata.xlsx` is the name of the excel file and `text` is the sheet name.

I want that whenever `getCSV()` is called it checks that if a sheet with the same `text` name also exists, if yes then it should update the new entries into that sheet. Else if that `text` name sheet does not exist it creates a new sheet and enters the values into that.

I am calling the `getCSV()` inside a `tkinter` GUI like this

```
self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.ok2)
```

```
def ok2(self):
        self.interval=str(self.variable_a.get())
        self.shorttrend=str(self.variable_b.get())
        self.longtrend=str(self.variable_c.get())
        self.mic=str(self.variable_d.get())
        symbols=getTickers(self.mic)
        self.getCSV(symbols)
        print("done")
```

As for the problem, I found this related question's solution like this.

```
import xlsxwriter
list_name = ["first sheet", "second sheet", "third sheet"]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(<Your full path>)
for sheet_name in list_name:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
    worksheet.write('A1', sheet_name)

workbook.close()
```

But I can't think of how to use this in my case as I don't have a ready-made list but it should create a new sheet whenever the function is called.

Comment: XlsxWriter does not _read_ data, it only writes data. If you want to actually interact with an already existing file, then you might want to look into another package. The documentation for XlsxWriter has a [list of alternatives](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/alternatives.html) that you can choose from.

Comment: The `openpyxl` module allows Python program to read and modify Excel files.